# Not able to update value in mdc-dialog using ngModel

Tags: angular6, mdc, ngmodel, mdc-components

I tried to update the input field using ngModel:

```
<input type="text" #fsect="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fsec" />
```

But the value is not updated inside a `<mdc-dialog>`.

I have imported FormsModule in app.module.ts file. But then also I am having issue.

NB: I am using Angular 6

Any possible solution!

Comment: I used injection **@Inject(MDC_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any** for populating the dialog element. But some of the elements like a date picker were added to the project as a JS file. In the date picker input I am not able to populate the value as "date.selectedDate". 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives]
at checkAndUpdateView
at callViewAction
at execEmbeddedViewsAction
at checkAndUpdateView
at callViewAction
at execComponentViewsAction
at checkAndUpdateView

at callViewAction`